# Wordpress 3.5 install error

Tags: plugins, errors, internal-server-error

Im trying to install the wordpress on my root folder but i got this message when i try to enter on url.

```
PHP Warning:  require(./wp-blog-header.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\home\businessinfo\web\index.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required './wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.;c:\php5\includes') in E:\home\businessinfo\web\index.php on line 17
```

What is that?

Comment: Does the file `wp-blog-header.php` exist in `E:\home\businessinfo\web`?

Comment: yes, i only uploaded the content zip of wordpress 5.1

Comment: I seriously doubt it was installed correctly.